# c++ boost::archives and mySql BLOBs , error with deserialization

Tags: c++, mysql, serialization, boost, blob

I'm rather new to c++, mysql and boost...

I'm trying to store c++ objects in a mySQL database, using BLOBs.

I'm using boost::archive to serialize and deserialize my objects.

Storing the blobs seems to work fine, but my program crashes when I try to deserialize the result blob.
I would really appriciate a hint on how to make this work.

My goal is to store more complex objects, but for now, I'm trying with a very simple class :

```
class user
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & id_;
        ar & name_;
        ar & age_;
    }
    int id_;        
    std::string name_;
    int age_;

public:
    user () {};  
    user (int id,std::string name, int age) 
    {
        id_ = id;
        name_ = name;
        age_ = age;

    };
    int id(){
        return id_;
    };
    std::string name(){
        return name_;
    };
    int age(){
        return age_;
    };
};
```

And here is the main function :

```
int main(){
    // a test object
    user u1(1,"myName",20);

    // serialization
    std::stringstream str;
    { 
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(str);
        oa << u1;
    }

    //mysql
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *sqlRes;
    sql::PreparedStatement *prep_stmt;
    try {
        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->  connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "mypass");
        stmt = con->createStatement();

        //test database with a table named users containing only one column, a BLOB(10000)
        stmt->execute("use test");

        prep_stmt = con -> prepareStatement ("insert into users(obj) VALUES(?)");
        prep_stmt->setBlob(1,&str);
        prep_stmt->execute();
    } 
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        //some stuff...
        (...)
    }

    //Reading the only element in the table
    sqlRes = stmt->executeQuery("select * from users");
    sqlRes->next();
    std::istream *blobdata = sqlRes->getBlob(1);

    //trying to deserialize the blob...
    user newUser;
    {
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(*blobdata); //crashes at this line
        ia >> newUser;
    }

    //If it worked, we should see our original user data...
    cout << "id = "<< newUser.id() <<endl;
    cout << "name = "<< newUser.name() <<endl;
    cout << "aeg = "<< newUser.age() <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know I'm probably doing something terribly wrong, but I can't figure it out!

Please help me, thanks.

---

**EDIT 1:**

getBlob() returns a null_ptr, and I don't know why.

If I do this instead to get the object back :

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << sqlRes->getString(1);

user newUser;
{
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss); 
    ia >> newUser;
}
```

It works and the object is recovered properly... Not sure it would work for more complex objects though.

---

**EDIT 2:**

It turns out there is something wrong in my environnement since @sehe (thanks for your help) tried the same thing I did and it worked for him. So the original code above is actually correct.

Comment: Please post some stack traces or error messages.

Comment: We had the same problem recently. We traced it to an error in the mysql c++ wrapper so we built our own around the mysql c library.

Comment: @AlexVogel When debugging in VS2012, I get the error message : "Unhandled exception at 0x5C6A884E (msvcp110.dll) in BlobOjb.exe:  : 0xC0000005 : Access violation reading location 0x00000000." Hmmm, why "0x0000000" ?!

Comment: @RichardHodges Makes sense. "Don't live with broken windows! Just replace the facade." Did the bug get reported?

Comment: @AlexVogel And the stack traces loks like :" > msvcp110.dll!std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::getloc() Ligne 130 C++
  rSqlnObj4.exe!boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive,char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_binary_iprimitive<class boost::archive::binary_iarchive,char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,bool) C++
  rSqlnObj4.exe!main() Ligne 72 C++
  rSqlnObj4.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Ligne 536 C
"

Comment: @RilDank That should be in the question. Partly because then people can read it without having a seizure

Comment: @sehe Sorry about that, my very first post here.  I'll do well next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have just taken the time to completely replay the example.

It works for me. I create a database like this:

```
 create database test;
 use test;
 create table users (obj mediumblob NULL);
```

I compile the following program (replace the database user/name as appropriate):

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class user
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & id_;
        ar & name_;
        ar & age_;
    }
    int id_;        
    std::string name_;
    int age_;

public:
    user () {};  
    user (int id,std::string name, int age) 
    {
        id_ = id;
        name_ = name;
        age_ = age;

    };
    int id(){
        return id_;
    };
    std::string name(){
        return name_;
    };
    int age(){
        return age_;
    };
};

int main(){
    // a test object
    user u1(1,"myName",20);

    // serialization
    std::stringstream str;
    { 
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(str);
        oa << u1;
    }

    //mysql
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *sqlRes;
    sql::PreparedStatement *prep_stmt;
    try {
        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->  connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "*********");
        stmt = con->createStatement();

        //test database with a table named users containing only one column, a BLOB(10000)
        stmt->execute("use test");

        prep_stmt = con -> prepareStatement ("insert into users(obj) VALUES(?)");
        prep_stmt->setBlob(1,&str);
        prep_stmt->execute();
    } 
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        //some stuff...
        exit(255);
    }

    //Reading the only element in the table
    sqlRes = stmt->executeQuery("select * from users");
    sqlRes->next();
    std::istream *blobdata = sqlRes->getBlob(1);

    //trying to deserialize the blob...
    user newUser;
    {
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(*blobdata); //crashes at this line
        ia >> newUser;
    }

    //If it worked, we should see our original user data...
    std::cout << "id   = " << newUser.id()   << std::endl;
    std::cout << "name = " << newUser.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "aeg  = " << newUser.age()  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE** This leaks resources. You will want to fix that.

When running it, it prints

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ ./test
id   = 1
name = myName
aeg  = 20
```

And mysql shows:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| obj                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        serialization::archive
                                                   myName    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I have verified that the column index is correct and being explicit when selecting columns gives the same result.

Comment: Very cunnning avoiding the question whether `getBlob(...)` returned null

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... getBlob(1) returns a null_ptr but why ?

Comment: The documentation should be able to help there. Perhaps increase logging /tracing

Comment: @RilDank Have updated my answer in response to the information added to the question

Comment: Thanks for your update. Indeed, setBlob(1,&str) does work, and I've checked again, the column is a BLOB (using 'DESCRIBE <table>' in mysql client)

Comment: @RilDank FWIW I've tested it and it works for me. Can you compare your program/table to that?

Comment: thank you for your time. Even if I use the exact same table as you did, and the exact same code, getBlob() still returns NULL for me. So I guess there must be something wrong in my environment. I'm using the pre-built libraries for the mysql/c++ connector. Would it help if I build them myself ? Any idea of what could be wrong in my environment? Thanks again. (BTW, after execution, the state of my table is the same as yours)